# How to use Python websocktes to send response to only one party?

Tags: jquery, python, sockets, websocket, flask

It is a Flask app.

I am leaning about websockts. What I am tying in is that, when I write in editor1 all the content of editor1 goes to editor2 of the connected user not mine editor2 and vice-verse. But seems like right now it is not happening and when I write mine and other connected users both textarea get updated. please help

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            namespace = '/test'; // change to an empty string to use the global namespace

            var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
            });

            socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
                $('textarea#editor2').val(msg.data);
            });

            $('textarea#editor1').keyup(function(event) {
                socket.emit('my broadcast event', {data: $('#editor1').val()});
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flask-SocketIO Test</h1>
    <textarea rows=10 cols=50 id="editor1"></textarea>
    <textarea rows=10 cols=50 id="editor2"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Flask code:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import time
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
thread = None


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('new.html')


@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    pass
#    session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
#    emit('my response',
#         {'data': message['data'], 'count': session['receive_count']})


@socketio.on('my broadcast event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
    emit('my response',
         {'data': message['data'], 'count': session['receive_count']},
         broadcast=True)


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    print('my response', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0})


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask-SocketIO does not currently have a "send to all users but myself" option right now, if you broadcast something then all users will get it, including the sender.

One solution is to include something that identifies the sender in the message payload, so that on the client side you can check if the message that was received came from the same user or a different one.

Another option (that may or may not work in your situation) is to not use the broadcast feature and instead send the message directly to the intended user. You can do this with the "rooms" feature, by putting each user in a different room, then sending messages to the proper room.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, 1st solution looks good. I am gonna try that. 

Using rooms still prints to both users.

Comment: If you put the users on different rooms, say "room_user1" and "room_user2", then you can have the server send a message to "room_user2" as a response to an event from user1, and that should not trigger a copy of the message sent to user1.